# maven-war-plugin maven-compiler-plugin

Tags: maven, plugins, war

i'm new to maven; I need to compile and packaging 2 war file in two different directory even if the source are the same (change only the web.xml file).

try to explain better:

directory structure of LT:

```
 <DIR>          LT1_war
  <DIR>          LT_war
                 pom.xml
```

a part of the pom is:

```
<modules>
        <module>LT_war</module>
        <module>LT1_war</module>
</modules>


inside the folder LT_war there is a pom and src-->main-->java
                                                         resources
                                                         webapp
```

this compile successful and also i packaging in a war LT_war (to deploy to tomcat)

I need a way in order to compile inside the directory LT1_war (using the source that are in the LT_war directory) and packaging using the webapp inside the LT_war directory (just changing the web.xml file)

I've try to write the pom inside the directory LT1_war but when i lunch mvn packaging it tell me:

```
[INFO] lt ................................................ SUCCESS [3.995s]
[INFO] LT ................................................ SUCCESS [1:12.629s]
[INFO] LT1 ............................................... FAILURE [41.367s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:59.716s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jul 08 23:50:43 CEST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/200M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.0:war (default-war) on project LT1: Error assembling WAR: Deployment descriptor: D:\attivi
taTomcat7\LT\LT1_war\target\LT1\WEB-INF\web.xml does not exist. -> [Help 1]:
```

this is a part of the pom file inside LT1_war:

```
<build>
    <finalName>LT1</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>../LT_war/src/</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>**/.svn/**</excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>exploded</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exploded</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>war</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>war</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a few things that I kindly consider terribly wrong with what you're doing:

- A Maven project should **never** access files that are outside of its own module's folder. So LT1 please stay out of LT's folder!
- Try to keep WAR projects small if you can. Modularize your code anyway, and make the WAR just depend on JAR files that contain the actual meat
- One WAR file "borrowing" stuff from the other WAR might then be better fixed by having both WAR files depend on the code that you moved into such JAR file(s)
- Stop using Java 5 if you reasonably can; it's been EOL since 2009. Also, consider moving your source/target levels to the parent project, so you don't redefine the same, yet have a consistent Java version
- Talking about old versions, how come you even still have `.svn` folders that you need to exclude (for a while now there's only a `.svn` folder in the root of your Subversion work space, that wouldn't affect the Maven WAR plugin)

So your project structure could look like this:

```
ROOT
   MEAT (packaging JAR, where your classes live)
   LT (packaging WAR, depends on MEAT)
   LT1 (packaging WAR, depends on MEAT, and stays the heck out of LT)
```

---

Addition (forgotten some aspect, as pointed out in comment)...

While MEAT is of packaging JAR, you want it to also include stuff that you had going into `webapp` without it ending up on the classpath. Provided you're using a fairly recent `servlet-api`, this can be achieved by giving MEAT a resources folder as follows:

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/...
```

E.g. `.../META-INF/resources/flower.jpeg` will appear in the deployed WAR as `<context root>/flower.jpg` (instead of it just being added to the Java class path).

Comment: thanks, but how I can accomplish this; in other words how to configure both plugin maven-compiler-plugin and org.apache.maven.plugins in order to do that?

Answer (score 0):

> I need a way in order to compile inside the directory LT1_war (using the source that are in the LT_war directory) and packaging using the webapp inside the LT_war directory (just changing the web.xml file)

Generally, you compile from the root.  It's not convenient to do what you're asking to do but it can be done by using the `--also-make` command line option.